# Why is the nav menu getting cut off? We want the white space to fill behind the menu items

Tags: javascript, html, css

Something happened and now our nav menu is getting cut off. We can't figure out what's going on... if you go to the page you'll see what I mean. Github page: https://tcffo.github.io/

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to add `height: 60px` or something to your `id` `#header`

Answer (score 1):

```
#header nav {
    letter-spacing: 0.075em;
    position: absolute;
    right: 1.5em;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    top: 0.75em;
}
```

`position` absolute takes your nav out of the layout. `#header` is not, speaking in terms of layout, empty, as `nav` has been taken out of it.

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/position#Absolute_positioning)

> **Absolute positioning**
>
> Elements that are positioned relatively are still considered to be in the normal flow of elements in the document. In contrast, an element that is positioned absolutely is taken out of the flow and thus takes up no space when placing other elements. The absolutely positioned element is positioned relative to nearest positioned ancestor (non-static). If a positioned ancestor doesn't exist, the initial container is used.

**Note: an element that is positioned absolutely is taken out of the flow and thus takes up no space when placing other elements.**

Answer (score 1):

You can fix this using a couple of different ways. It's the absolute positioning of the #nav element that's causing your problem.

Option 1:

```
#header>#nav{

    position:relative

}

#nav>ul{
    float:right;
}
```

If you want to keep the absolute positioning, you can just adjust the height of the header bar instead.

Option 2:

```
#header{

    height:65px;

}
```